# How can I get a Discord.py time stamp without CTX?

Tags: python, timestamp, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot. One of its features is logging leaving and entering members in a logging channel. The on_member_join and on_member_remove events only take the member perameter. I'm wondering how to put a timestamp in my embed without ctx. I know it's possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: Can you maybe share your code/approaches too?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current time via `datetime`, for this you only have to import a module. If you post the whole thing in an embed you can do the following:

```py
import datetime # 1
from datetime import datetime # 2

@commands.Cog.listener / @client.event / @bot.event
async def on_member_join
embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
```

If you want to send these kind of messages you have to define a channel since `ctx.send` will not work, so rather go for:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener / @client.event / @bot.event
channel = self.bot.get_channel(ChannelID) # Or bot/client.get_channel
async def on_member_join
embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
[...]
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

If you have defined a channel and just want to send it as a normal message you can put `datetime` into an f-string:

```py
await channel.send(f"{datetime}")
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Module datetime has no attribute "utcnow"

Comment: Then try to use `datetime.datetime.utcow`